# For MYSQL 5.7.31 - Which Timeout variable should be changed for a transport connection: Connection timed out

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql 5.7.31 with C# on Linux ubuntu

When I programmatically delete a large table or drop a database I get this timeout

```
Stack=MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (110): Connection timed out
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

To fix this I've attempted

1. I added this to my connection string

> Connect Timeout=60

2. I added this to my mysqld.cnf, Restarted and checked it show variables.  The log file shows it timed-out after 42 seconds.

> connect_timeout=60000
> interactive_timeout=60000
> wait_timeout=60000

I think the issue is "Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out."

But not sure which variable needs to be changed to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: increase the number evenhiger till you get no timeout

Comment: I had it set to 60secons, and the logs say it timed out after 40 seconds. so apparently the changes I made did not effect the system.

Comment: dot net has also a timeout, but you should ckeck if there a proccesses in the processlist which is blocling, because drop should be fast and the increase it further tha 60 seconds

Comment: my guess is the changes i made were not correct for a transport exception timout.  Are the variables I changed the correct ones?

Comment: tzhe ysql connector has the same timeout as the server has, if you don't wnat t find out which culperate is the cause, increase n both sides the time out whne nned be to 35000000 and see what comes out, but increasing all timeout gradually ine at a time you find out which is braking up the conection. also when you enable general lock you see how long the delete actualöly needs.

Answer (score 0):

[connect_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) is used only when the client and server are performing a handshake, during the initial client connection. Increasing this helps if the client gets errors like `Lost connection to MySQL server...`. The default is 10 seconds.

I've never had a reason to tune this variable, because if the client can't connect within 10 seconds, it's probably blocked by a firewall, or routing, or else the MySQL Server is simply not running or is listening on another port. Increasing the timeout will not help in these cases.

[wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) helps the client is idle for a long time between queries. The client is not considered idle if the query executes for a long time. The idle time starts when a query finishes. The default is 8 hours (28800 seconds). If your app is timing out *during* an SQL statement execution, then this variable is not relevant.

[interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) is just like wait_timeout, but for "interactive" clients. The only client that is in this category is the [mysql command-line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html). You can ignore this timeout variable, unless you're working on the mysql CLI.

You might need to tune [net_read_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout) or [net_write_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_write_timeout). But I wouldn't expect either of these to be necessary.

Tip: Use XFS as the filesystem for the MySQL datadir on Linux. It's *much* faster to drop tables or schemas, regardless of how large they are. XFS gives better performance for other work too, not just dropping tables.